# My collision element is defaulting to a circle of 1 meter in rviz

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My collision element is defaulting to a circle of 1 meter in rviz. I specify all collision elements for a box .4x.2 with wheels .05 length on either side of the .2 out .05 from the sides making it .4 x .4 total.

When I select the collision check box in the Robot Model tab in RVIZ it shows a circle of  1 meter radius.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/80801/my-collision-element-is-defaulting-to-a-circle-of-1-meter-in-rviz./) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2013-09-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry...bad element def:...this process is prone to manual errors of all kinds.

---

Originally posted by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) with karma: 713 on 2013-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0